# HarmonyOS wearable vibrator not activating

Tags: wearables, harmonyos

I'm creating a HarmonyOS Wearable app using the JS Framework and I want to use the vibrator. The watch definitely has a vibrator because I can feel it when I use the scroll weel in the settings app.

So I requested the system_grant `ohos.permission.VIBRATE` permission in the `config.json` file as described [here](https://developer.harmonyos.com/en/docs/documentation/doc-guides/security-permissions-guidelines-0000000000029886#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001072906209__section5561355101318)

```json
"module": {
...
    "reqPermissions": [
      {
        "name": "ohos.permission.VIBRATE",
        "reason": "Make vibrates"
      }
    ]
...
}
```

Then it should be simple to use the imported vibrator like this

```js
import vibrator from '@system.vibrator';
export default {
    // ...
    onShow() {
        console.log("VIBRATOR");
        vibrator.vibrate({
            mode : "long",
            success: () => console.debug("Vibrator Success"),
            fail : (data, code) => console.log("Vibrator handle fail, data = ${data}, code = ${code}"),
            complete : () => console.debug("Vibrator Complete")
        });
    }
    // ...
}
```

I do get the `VIBRATOR` log in `HiLog` but non of the other logs in the vibrator callbacks nor does the device vibrate.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
I noticed a bunch of error logs after the `VIBRATOR` log. I cant figure out what they mean so I'm posting them here.

```
D 03B00/JSApp: app Log: VIBRATOR
E 03900/Ace: [<private>      (<private>)] ace Log: [JS Framework] Failed to invoke the event handler of "viewappear" on div (_root):
E 03900/Ace:  TypeError: value has no property
E 03900/Ace: [<private>      (<private>)] Qjs FireAsyncEvent FAILED !! jsCall: <private>
E 03900/Ace: [<private>       (<private>)] [DUMP] <private>
E 03900/Ace: [<private>       (<private>)] <private>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS API document is written based on the wearables. The standard usage of smart devices is as follows:

```
vibrator.vibrate({
    mode: "short"
});
```

or

```
vibrator.vibrate()；
```

Comment: Hi @shirley. I tried it the way you indicated but I get the same result. I noticed I get a bunch of error logs after the `VIBRATOR` log so I updated my question to and add them there.

Comment: hi@Daniel,could you pls provide your SDK Version and HarmonyOS Version for us to check?Like following :SDK（API Version 5）js 2.1.1.20; watch Version 2.0.0.118; HarmonyOS Version:2.0.0; device version :XXX

Comment: Hi @shirley. It seems I had an older OS version. I got an update and now the vibrator seems to work.